# Disable Apache Automatic Startup on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I am running CentOS which has Apache installed.  It automatically starts up (script is in /etc/init.d).  Since this is a standalone database server, I have no need for Apache to be running.  How do I disable the startup?  Just delete the file in /etc/init.d?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`# chkconfig <servicename> off`

Then to verify:

`chkconfig --list | grep <servicename>`

So probably `chkconfig httpd off` , you want to go read about runlevels in `man init`.  The verification should return `httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off`.  If you want to stop it without restarting run `/etc/init.d/httpd stop`.  All of these will need to be done with root privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Right, you can also do it using setup configuration tool:

```
sudo setup
```